# Need explanation of an expression

Tags: c++, c

I'm have trouble in understanding this expression :

The expression is :

```
if( !(a<00.0 || a>0.0))
 a=b;
```

Where `a` and `b` both are `float` variable.

Is there anyone could explian it to me?
I would be so appreciate for your help.

Thanks!

edit--------------------first time for additional-------

It really is that `00.0` in the original code I read.

Now I add someting for it. `a` is a float array, `b` is the initial value for `a`.

At the beginning ,initialize `a` by `b`,then calculate a with other functions,at last, check for the `a values`,if `a values` don't match some conditions,let the value euqal to `b`.

```
float *a;
float b;
int N,i;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
a[i]=b;//initialize

function(a,.....)
{
//calculate a[i];
}

for(i=0;i<N,i++)
if( a<0.0 ||
    (a>1000.0 && a!=b) ||
    !(a<00.0 || a>=0.0) )
a[i]=b;
```

Comment: What specifically about that expression do you not understand? Is it the `!`, the `||`, the `00`, .., what?

Comment: To answer the question you're asking: I'm absolutely positive that there is someone around here who can explain this to you.

Comment: What trouble you are having with this check??

Comment: sorry ,I just want to know what the expression means @kaylum

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Some other friends said to me ,it may want to identify whether  a equal to 0,the reason is in some machine the float zero is not absolute 0.0

Comment: Thanks for @Rahul Bharadwaj 's editting, I'm so sorry for reject your edit,"**This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.**" ,I was so anxious to add some addtions that forgot to see the edit flag.I feel sorry about that,and appreciate for your help too.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, this appears to simplify to

```
if (a == 0)
    a = b;
```

However, if `a` is a NaN, this simplification gives different results.  Any comparison with a NaN is false, so the more complicated expression will assign `b` to `a` if `a` is zero or a NaN.

Comment: Good answer. Forgot about NaN completely.

Comment: Thanks,after conpared with other comditions,just like you said,a need to compare with 0.And NaN is another very inportant influence factor, I will add it into if conditions.